# Stop sending "processing order" e-mail when WooCommerce order status pending payment

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

I have a strange problem with WooCommerce shop. When the customer orders something on my shop with Klarna or PayPal gateway, the user is getting the processing order e-mail, even though the order is not yet processed by Klarna or PayPal.

Is there any possibility to stop sending processing order e-mails when WooCommerce order status is pending payment?

I have tried this code but it doesn't change anything

```
function manipulate_woocommerce_email_sending($email_class){
    remove_action('woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold_notification', array($email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order'], 'trigger'));
    add_action('woocommerce_order_status_on-hold_to_processing_notification', array($email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order'], 'trigger'));
}
add_action ('woocommerce_email', 'manipulate_woocommerce_email_sending');
```

Comment: Have you had a look at https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/unhookremove-woocommerce-emails/ ?

Comment: yes i tried this: but no luck /**
 * Unhook and remove WooCommerce default emails.
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_email', 'unhook_those_pesky_emails' );

function unhook_those_pesky_emails( $email_class ) {
  // New order emails
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
  }

Comment: What about disabling the processing email via WooCommerce > Settings > Emails, then select Processing Orders (Manage Button), and disabling the email?

Comment: that will disable the processing email not pending payment.I am looking for something that disable the pending payment the order they pay with paypal or klarna and they are not processed by them.